# ValueError: x and y must be the same size, machine learning using sklearn doing linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, multidimensional-array, plot, sparse-matrix, linear-regression

First, I did data preprocessing to convert the data into a sparse matrix using as X, and Y is a list of label. then I applied machine learning

```
X_train_kera, X_test_kera, y_train_kera, y_test_kera = train_test_split(disc_vec_tfidf, y_keras, test_size=0.5)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
cls = LinearRegression()
cls.fit(X_train_kera,y_train_kera)
```

Then I tried plot the linear regression graph

```
plt.scatter(X_train_kera[:,0],y_test_kera,color='black')
plt.plot(X_train_kera[:,0], y_pred, color='blue')

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

And it gives me error says x and y must be the same size. I then did some googling, And I found the shape of X_train_keras is different from the y_test_keras. I tried use [:,0], but it still didn't work, can someone help me with this?

```
 X_train_kera.shape
(17330, 2746))
y_test_kera.shape
(17331,)
```

Comment: 'y_pred=cls.predict(X_test_kera)'  I forget a line of code, sorry guys

Answer (score 0):

Your output with shape explains it. 
Your X_train has 17330 rows 
therefore, if you pull out the first column and all rows i.e X_train_kera[:,0] 
You have 17330 rows and one column.
Your y_test_kera.shape is 17331, which explains why there is a dimension mismatch

Comment: oh shoot I missed that, so I am missing one dimension from y_test_kera?